# nginx wont start after it was killed

Tags: unix, nginx, server-side

I am very new to nginx, and I accidentally killed the nginx process and now it wont start. "sudo service nginx start" gives me no output but I can't see the process when I run "ps -aux". I may have done some change in some of the config files, but I think I managed to revert all my changes.

When I type sudo nginx -t I get:

nginx: the configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf syntax is ok
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test is successful

I have also checked all the files in /var/log/nginx, but they have not any logs since I killed the process.

Thanks in advance, 
Markus

Comment: Server configuration questions are off topic here and should be asked on serverfault.com but, even there, this question will be closed if you don't supply more information than that such as the config file.

Comment: provide output of : `sudo service nginx status`

Comment: No output for sudo service nginx status @FarhadFarahi

Comment: thats weired, `dpkg-query -l | grep nginx`

Comment: sudo: dpkg-query: command not found. I am on red hat. However, "sudo rpm -qa | grep nginx":
´nginx-filesystem-1.6.3-7.el7.noarch
pcp-pmda-nginx-3.10.6-2.el7.x86_64
nginx-1.6.3-7.el7.x86_64'´

Answer (score 0):

From your rpm -qa output it seems your OS is CentOS 7.x

To check the nginx status you should use:

```
systemctl status nginx
```

To start the nginx service use:

`systemctl start nginx`

If it returns error and won't start you could issue also a `journalctl -xe` to get additional information and see why the service didn't start